# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError even when changing the property through @Output event

Tags: angular

I am trying to update a property on the parent component through child component's event.

I searched on internet that this should be done through `@Output` as it is the standard way to pass data from child component to parent component

This is my parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: '<app-child (onCountUpdateEvent)="onCountUpdate($event)"></app-child>',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Parent
{
    count = 0;

    onCountUpdate(count: number) {
      this.count = count;
    }
  }
}
```

On child I have the event emmitter like this

```
@Output() onCountUpdateEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And on one of the control's event of child form I am emitting this event to update the count like this

```
this.onCountUpdateEvent.emit(4);
```

I am not getting even doing it through `@Output` and even when the property belongs to only parent and only parent code is updating it I am still getting this error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '3'. Current value: '4'

I am not updating this value directly from child then why this error is coming

**EDIT**

Drilled down to the real issue.

I am using Devextreme DataGrid, so my code is not working only when I emit the event on `onSaved` event of the `dx-data-grid` else it works perfectly fin from all the other places

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using `ChangeDetectorRef` to detect the new changes on  the parent component

```
constructor(private cd:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The child view never load after this change. Everything becomes empty.